# What's the meaning of "make -j" without a number

Tags: makefile

I am using "make" command to compile. I know if I use "make -jN", N indicates the job number. But if I don't use any number after -j, what does it mean?

Answer (score 8):

No number means no limit.

From the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel) [emphasis mine]:

> If the ‘`-j`’ option is followed by an integer, this is the number of recipes to execute at once; this is called the number of job slots. If there is **nothing looking like an integer** after the ‘`-j`’ option, there is **no limit on the number of job slots**. The default number of job slots is one, which means serial execution (one thing at a time).

Comment: @Jade If `-j` is not defined, the number of jobs is 1. If `-j` is defined without a number, the number of jobs is not limited.

Comment: If no integer after -j, it will auto detect the max capacity?

Comment: @Jade Unlimited means It might fork more jobs than you have processor cores available.